# In Catia V5 CAA, how to update a CATPart by code?

Tags: catia, caa

I'm currently developing CAA commands in CATIA V5 in C++.

I'm trying to automatically update a CATPart after several modifications in it, but nothing seems to work...
From an element inside my part, I retrieve the CATIAPart object and update it, but in session nothing seems to happen, I tried to UI activate the object before doing the update but it does not change the outcome.

What would be a good way to do it ?

Comment: What have you modified in the part? (both part and product have a update method)

Comment: I created bodies that depend on external referencies, these are not updated as well, and if I try to update them still nothing happens and everything in the part (the part itself, the bodies, the external references) are not up to date.

I also tried to update directly the product, but nothing more happened. I also always check with the CATIAlias interface on which feature I'm working on, and everything is fine here, I'm moving inside the hierarchy as expected.

Comment: Can you manual update these features? Does _UpdateObject_ work with these non updated features?

Comment: In session, a manual local update does the trick, that's what bothers me, I know my features are correcty built because of that.

I didn't try UpdateObject method, I thought Update would loop on every child, I'll try it.

Comment: After testing the UpdateObject method on CATIAPart, I see that one of the bodies fails (but I don't know how/why), and the others succeed, but in session 0 bodies are no up to date.

Something else came up: I'm currectly working in a sub product to create my part and stuff, but if my UI active product is the root, everything works fine...

Comment: I figured out a bypass to force the update, it's quite ugly (or at least clearly not straightforward) and I would still like to find something better...

I created a catvbs macro that does the part update, and called it from caa code with the CATScriptUtilities::ExecuteScript method.
The update is asynchronous, I assume this is why it works and the other methods did not, but I can't figure out why.

But hey, it works...